# What questions to expect during a junior javascript developer interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, developer, junior

I was invited in for a chat at a digital studio next week and I'm just going over some example questions etc.

The company seems really amazing. They make good looking products (Apps and the like) for small start-ups, nothing corporate or boring, just some cool people making cool things.

So I'm wondering what sort of questions I should expect? I will be preparing for the usual questions but any tips or guides would greatly help.

Comment: Which country are you in? Interviewing techniques differ greatly between countries, the UK is more behavioural based whereas the US places a lot of emphasis on technical proficiency.

Comment: Try rephrasing your question and state a certain goal you'd like to achieve. _'What sort of question should I expect'_ & _'any tips or guides would greatly help'_ is very broad and primarily opinion-based..

Answer (score 5):

You should expect to write code. Preferably, work on personal projects consistently in the weeks leading up to your interview. This will train your brain to be in JavaScript mode so you don't fumble JavaScript's syntax while trying to implement an algorithm they've asked you to write.

Search the web for "JavaScript exercises" or "JavaScript interview exercises" to find small exercises you can try to implement yourself. There's a good chance you will not practice the exact exercise they give you, but this will still get you thinking about how to approach a random problem.

I'm sure you already know this, but make sure you know the basics, such as the difference between let/var and the different ways to define a function. They also may ask you something along the lines of "what have you learned recently?", "what personal projects have you worked on?", and "are there any new features in JavaScript that excite you?" Try to have answers ready.

Best of luck!

Comment: This is also true when you have worked with several languages over the years. Doing prep work by doing some simple development using the language is helpful in refreshing your memory of the syntax and idiosyncrasies of a given language.

Comment: I agree, showing deep understanding by explaining different scopes of variables is just as important as being able to write simple code on the fly. My last company would always ask about the difference between "let" and "var", and it was a dealbreaker if someone would not know.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to put this as a comment but i don't have enough rep.
Anyway here is a [questionnaire](https://github.com/h5bp/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions/blob/master/src/questions/javascript-questions.md) for job interviews with basic/common questions of javascript.
Although the focus is for front end, the questionnaire has many of the basics like these questions:

> Basic JS Knowlegment
>
> - Explain event delegation.
> - Explain how `this` works in JavaScript.
> - What language constructions do you use for iterating over object properties and array items?
> - Can you describe the main difference between the Array.forEach() loop and Array.map() methods and why you would pick one versus the
>     other?
> - Explain the difference between: function Person(){}, var person = Person(), and var person = new Person()?
> - Can you explain what Function.call and Function.apply do? What's the notable difference between the two?
> - Explain the differences on the usage of foo between function foo() {} and var foo = function() {}
> - What's the difference between an "attribute" and a "property"?
> - What is the difference between `==` and `===`?
> - What are the differences between variables created using let, var or const?
>
> Intermediate questions
>
> - Explain how prototypal inheritance works.
> - What's the difference between a variable that is: null, undefined or undeclared?
> - How would you go about checking for any of these states?
> - What is a closure, and how/why would you use one?
> - What's a typical use case for anonymous functions?
> - What's the difference between host objects and native objects?
> - Explain Function.prototype.bind.
> - Explain "hoisting".
> - Describe event bubbling.
> - Describe event capturing.
> - Why is it called a Ternary operator, what does the word "Ternary" indicate?
> - Explain the difference between synchronous and asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 3):

I've held a couple of interviews with prospective employees supposed to work with js, ng, node & pgsql and therefore put a little questionnaire together to rate the candidates.

The first part doesn't even consist of any programming but rather general IT-questions to see if they have even the most basic understandings of computers and networks:

- 1.1 Describe the purpose and the functionality of a proxy-server & reverse proxy-server
- 1.2 Name & describe the layers of the OSI-model
- 1.3 What the difference between a router and a switch
- 1.4 Name a couple of firewalls you are familiar with
- 1.5 Describe the functionality of a compiler and an interpretor
- 1.6 Describe the programming paradigms of object-oriented and function-oriented programming languages
- 1.7 etc.

In the second part I focus my questions on JS, starting with simple quesions:

- 2.1 What is JavaScript?
- 2.2 What is NodeJS?
- 2.3 Name and explain the different data-types.
- 2.4 What is a function-scope?
- 2.5 What are global variables?
- 2.6 What is 'this' keyword in JavaScript?
- 2.7 Which symbol is used for comments in Javascript?
- 2.8 Whats the difference between == and === ?
- 2.9 etc..

In the third part I focus on Angular specific questions such as:

- 3.1 Explain what 'declarations', 'providers', and 'imports' do.
- 3.2 Explain AOT compilation
- 3.3 What is a subscription?
- 3.4 What is an observable?
- 3.5 Explain the steps of the ng-lifecycle.
- 3.6 etc..

And in the fourth part I let them write a couple of semi-difficult SQL queries to see if they are familiar with db-operations.

Additionally, an interviewer could also ask you about past work experiences and projects you have worked on until now.

In the last part I tend to ask personal questions related to work-ethics, teamwork-capabilities and interpersonal skills.

So you see that such a questionnaire could just not only exist of pure js-related questions but could also contain a broad variety of questions related to front to backend and full-stack-development - depending on the needs of the company interviewing you.

Alltogether, including the candidates behaviour, rethorical skills, creativity, body-language and knowledge-base, I get a somehow clear picture if he's in the 'hire' or in the 'no-hire' fraction of the candidate-pool.

p.s.: It's always useful to familiarize yourself with a variety of sdk's and ide's and to get your hands dirty by developing some small projects beforehand. And obviously try to present yourself from the best side and show interest in the company as well by asking them a couple questions.  Good luck and may your secret sauce be with you!

Joel Spolsky's ["The Guerrilla Guide to Interviewing"](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/10/25/the-guerrilla-guide-to-interviewing-version-30/) is also inspiring and worth a read for both - interviewers and interviewees..